# How to read Excel in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have used below code in R script and it works fine but when run the same code in R-markdown it treats header as the first row. Please suggest whats missing?

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("Test.xlsx")
```

Comment: You might have better luck with `readxl::read_xls`. I don't know why that would be better, but I use it in an `Rmd` file and it works fine.

Comment: Actually, I meant `readxl::read_xlsx`. I assume you have it in the r script brackets @alienbeeq refers to.

Comment: ```readxl::read_xlsx``` still reads the header as row, while this code works fine with just R code file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create a new `Rmarkdown` file
2. Create a new `test.xlsx` file with the following content

   `name,age
   foo,10
   fooo,20`
3. And insert the following code into the `Rmarkdown` file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``` . (remove .)
## Untitled test

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
require("readxl")
d <- readxl::read_xlsx(path="U:\\profile\\desktop\\test.xlsx", sheet=1)
head(d)
```. (remove .)
````

Comment: I do not know how to escape ```` so had to connect with `.`, please remove `.` and it should work

Comment: The answer did not address the question of why the `readxl::read_excel` function reportedly works differently in Rmarkdown than outside of Rmarkdown. The user appears not to be using the R commands outside of the code fields as the answere assumes.

Comment: @abe I used the same,my bad that i didnt mention the rmarkdown syntax as well.Still it didnt work by just using file name in the working directory. I haven't got answer yet to it that why it works with pathname\\filename and not just with filename.

Comment: @Vaishali Saraswat it should work with **just** a `filename` too. Have a look, e.g., here https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html, they use a `filename`. To be able to work with **just a filename**, you need to create `rmarkdown project` https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/reproducible-projects-with-rstudio-and-r-markdown.html, hope this helps.